# Track each function call dynamically

Tags: php

I was wondering, can you make a function or something, that looks for other function calls across the site? I think, that if there is a master page, you could include it at the very top and it should work sitewise.

But I have no idea how to do this.

Kind of like `debug_backtrace();`, but global. In other words, a function that does something with a function that has been called after this function.

Well, I see that you could do this with a specific `call_user_func();`, therefore track everything what's going on, but.. any dynamic way?

Thanks in advance!

### Goal

The goal of this is to dynamically keep chain of called functions. So at some moment, for example, I require a value back from 3rd function in chain, so I can simply retrieve it with something like `$calls[2]; // the stored returned value or an array containing info about function + returned value`.

And it adds function data to chain on each call, where 1st call's `$key = 0`. So for debugging purposes, when my function fails which is **x** function in a row, I'd love to know information about previously called functions, maybe one has returned wrong value, resulting in error at some part later on.

Comment: do you want to do this without altering the called functions?

Comment: Question is not very clear. Can you edit and add information about the gioal you want to achieve?

Comment: AOP? http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/573-Current-State-of-AOP-for-PHP.html

Comment: @yi_H, yes, without altering the called function. Sometimes storing a data about function or returned value (if any) might come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for some [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) technique. You could write the weaved code to return immediately if some (global) flag (show trace) is not set, otherwise print the backtrace.

PHP doesn't support AOP directly but you can either patch the PHP core (complicated) or use tools to create (transform the) code based on the AOP weavings. I haven't used it for PHP yet, so you have to do more research on the web.

Comment: Something like... I create my own class, that controls all the site and works in some kind of AOP way? Wrapper for "everything", I guess?

Comment: yes, intercepts every method call and then you can control whether it actually does backtrace inspection or not. Intercepting all function calls is going to be definitely slow but it sounds like you do this for debugging, so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I have developed Go! AOP PHP library https://github.com/lisachenko/go-aop-php. It's a new generation library for 5.4 that introduce AOP concepts for any PHP applications. You can try it to define your own aspects )

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is, and I doubt if it would work and would be useful. Functions in turn call other functions, even the internal ones. Even the logging functions are functions themselves, so you end up with an enormous amount of information with which you can do virtually nothing relevant. If such a solution exists (it may), it won't be developed in PHP itself, but be a module that is loaded by or compiled in PHP.

If you want to log method calls to class instances, you could make some hook. You can make a class that implements `__call`. Then, for an instance you want to log, assign that instance to an instance of your log class, and assign that log class instance to the variable in which the original class was stored.

Then, each method call is directed to your class and you can log each call before you call the original method.

Comment: Or probably a global function `_c($function, $params = array()){}` that executes `call_user_func();` and log's the data I need. Plus works outside classes and stuff. Like a wrapper.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to call that function explicitly, I think, while `__call` is called implicitly for methods that don't exist. Or is there a `__c` magic function?

Comment: In that case, yeah you can, but that means you will have to call that special function for each function you want to call. That will make your code very messy. I wouldn't want to do that. Instead, look for a PHP module that may do this for you, or modify specific functions when you want to debug/profile/log them.

Comment: `AOP` looks more to the point at this time, and answers some of my other questions/theories at the same time. This answer contains usable information too, but, yeah.

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to diyism_trace.php:

http://code.google.com/p/diyism-trace/